# Google Sheets as Data Base With Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use google sheets with android but without java i am new to android and all i can find on google and youtube is how to use java with android and when i try the same i usually end up with one or more error either on importing or in some function i also get error when i just use direct google examples can someone please help me with this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-<API>-<VERSION>') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

i get error here with  compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'` i figured out its the version and i just changed it to compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.1'` the error is gone but i dont know any better

after this i tried to do what is shown in java quickstart sheets api https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java?hl=ja
but i keep getting error in importing `import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;`

is there any way i can do this without java and directly with kotlin?

edit :: i did change `com.google.apis:google-api-services-<API>-<VERSION>'` thats not the problem

Comment: You are using extremely out-of-date dependency versions.  `com.android.support` is entirely deprecated, and that version is outdated even for that.  I don't know what your problem is, but you should start with getting the latest versions of your dependencies

Comment: according to docs, you need to prepare your build.gradle like this: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/java-samples/blob/master/sheets/quickstart/build.gradle